# Kafka : a fault occurred in a recent unsafe memory access operation in compiled Java code

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

After publishing some messages to kafka , i am getting below error .
Please some one assist debug the issue .

And machine has sufficient memory .

```
user@kafka-1:/home/kafka/kafka/logs$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        95G   10G   80G  12% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            7.9G  4.0K  7.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  624K  1.6G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

a fault occurred in a recent unsafe memory access operation in compiled Java code

Comment: I had a similar error. The root cause was that the disk was full.

Answer (score 0):

Check logs.dir config when Kafka starts up from server.log file